# Can I use Google Play Games Services - Realtime Multiplayer in Unity Android Free?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-play-games

I have Unity 4 Free with android free, and I want to use Google Play Services Realtime Multiplayer.
Is this possible? Because from license comparison on Unity website I know that Android free doesn't have Socket support.

I want to use [Google's official Unity plugin](https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity).

Comment: you should just import it and play around with it, if you get the Socket exception while compiling then you cant use it, i dont see why you would get the socket exception, i use prime31 google play game services and it doesnt use sockets, maybe the same goes for the package you put up

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can. We've created an Android Plugin for Unity that has Google Play Game services, and we've never had an issue with RTM or TBM. Tested with Unity Free and Pro.